# Can I reuse an openssl x509store between separate ssl contexts?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a c++ application that creates several http clients to different endpoints using OpenSSL. During setup of the ssl context, I'm loading a Mozilla pem file into a single X509STORE object.

```
X509_STORE* thestore = globalstuffs::getInstance().x509store;
SSL_CTX_set_cert_store(sslctx_->native_handle(), thestore);
```

My thinking was to do this instead of loading from a file to save time going to disk each time with `sslctx_->load_verify_file(file);` or `sslctx_->set_default_verify_paths();`

There's no issue with a single client, but when I have more than one, during teardown of the ssl context on the second I get a fault in CRYPTO_free. The call stack shows X509_STORE_free down the line so I'm assuming it's an issue with using the same store. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Why separate contexts?

Comment: I have multiple endpoints with different sni values.  Can you safely share contexts simultaneously with multiple sockets?

Comment: Certainly, why not? Holding common trust and key material is exactly what the SSL context is for.

Comment: great .. I'm 98% sure that that does the trick.  I need some more testing to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I reuse an openssl x509store between separate ssl contexts?

You should reuse the same SSL Context if you have shared trust and key material. That's what it's for.